# Проблема с запоминанием Tabs Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

имеются вложенные табы, при перезагрузке страницы все сбрасывается до таба 1-го уровня, хотелось бы чтоб при перезагрузке открывался последний таб (вложенный). Благодарю за помощь!
Вот код:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="true">Profile</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab"> Profile </div>

    </div>
 </div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
        window.location.hash = '_' + $(this).attr('id');
    });
    if (window.location.hash) {
        $('[id="' + window.location.hash.substr(2) + '"]').trigger('click');
    } else {
        $('[data-toggle="tab"]:first').tab('show');
    }
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        $('[id="' + window.location.hash.substr(2) + '"]').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

[image: Скриншот]